# In Terraria, how do you kill the twins if your Vampire Knives or Legendary Terra Blade won't destroy them?

Tags: terraria-console

So I got some overpowered weapons from a friend and decided to start destroying bosses...killing Skeletron, the eye of cthulu and his brains, plus the eater or worlds and skeleton prime, and the wall of flesh...but then I hit a roadblock. I need help killing the twins...any advice?

Note: if it is important, I have hallowed armor, every NPC housed and I play Xbox 1/console

Answer (score 0):

Melee Weapon might be a good and strong choice for keeping Monsters away in your everyday living, but if it comes to bosses you are usually better off using ranged weapons of some sort.

Your question is put very broad and not that easy to answer, but you should consider swapping weapons.

If you are in Hardmode and you got arms dealer, I would consider buying the mini shark machine gun from him. Not only will it later become a much more potent mega shark, if you start gathering the materials, but also will it get you through fairly easy up to late mid game after beating Plantera.

Another factor in fighting bosses is the area you fight them in.
It might be easier to fight them in an arena composed of platforms so you can change level easy and evade attacks in all directions.
Wing might as well help in evading attacks.

Basic Designs for Arenas, guides for bosses and weapons and everything else is most easily found in the [Terraria Wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Terraria_Wiki).

It is one of the best Wikis out there and you will find help for any question you got with this game.

Comment: But...and thx for the advice...I am not like most players, the arena will help, but I am not a ranged character...I do have an unreal S.D.M.G. Though, I guess it doesn't hurt to try

Comment: So you want to stay melee but you want to kill further bosses.
A good arena, the rocket boots, wings, a good armor and the right trinkets will help you the most then. 
Vampie knives and terra blade have been among the best endgame melee weapons. Most of the other endgame melee weapons are endgame boss drops.
There is a page about melee weapons on the wiki as well.

Comment: I do have wings, I have more good things than I can remember that I can't access atm...I did see the page might, also...and once I get passed this boss, it'll just get harder from there, and it a Legendary Terra Blade will hardly work on the twins...hm...I could send a send a screenshot on what I have, but I dunno if I can

Comment: I don't think that helps, SE is usually focused on more general questions, that help everyone finding them, not so specified personal questions. Mods would tell you to read the Tour or Help center pages first, since your question is not phrased that clear. All i can say is, use the Wiki, wait for another answer or try your luck with the wikis Community pages. SE is not designated for opinion based answers, as well as long discussions in the comment section.